# Convert the render command in Yii2 to the smarty

Tags: php, yii, yii2, smarty, yii2-advanced-app

How to change this code in **.tpl** files?

**1)**

```
$ this-> render ('_form', [
     'model' => $ model,
 ]);
```

**2)**

```
GridView :: widget ([
     'dataProvider' => $ dataProvider,
     'filterModel' => $ searchModel,
     'columns' => [
         ['class' => 'yii \ grid \ SerialColumn'],

         'id',
         'title'

         ['class' => 'yii \ grid \ actioncolumn'],
     ],
 ]);
```

i changed number 2 to :

```
{GridView 'dataProvider'=$dataProvider,'filterModel'=$searchModel,columns=[  
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'title',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],    ]
 }
```

but this error Happened !! :   "too many shorthand attributes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Gridview

```
{GridView::widget([
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          'filterModel' => $searchModel,
          'columns' => [ 
               ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
               ['attribute' => 'id'],
               ['attribute' => 'title'],
               ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']
          ]
])}
```

where id and title is fields of your $dataProvider
And remember to use in top of the page

```
{use class="yii\grid\GridView"}
```

To render a tpl use:

```
{$this->render('_form.tpl', ['model' => $Model])}
```

Comment: tank you for your answer. render is work but grid view says :  Unexpected "=", expected one of: "","" , "]"

Comment: Sorry, my error :( you must write 'dataProvider '=>$dataProvider, 'filterModel' => $searchModel, I'll update my answer

Comment: it works! tank u,now, if i want show actions column like this : ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'] what should I do?

Comment: You must put it inside columns like this: 'columns' => [//other data, ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'] ]

Comment: I,m sorry but i wrote it same your code this error happened : Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::0

Comment: I've updated my answer, post your view code [docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty/tree/master/docs/guide)